# Learning to think like a programmer

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

I'm pretty interested in game development and I've tried a couple of platforms and languages. Including libgdx and game maker studio, all without any real success. I'm currently using unity and it's the farthest I have ever gotten, but it just doesn't feel right. I follow tutorials and learn how to do certain things, but it just feels like I'm a parrot learning a new word I don't really understand what I'm doing just kind of memorizing stuff. I'm trying to become a good game developer, but I just don't know how to practice c# in a way where I will gain actual understanding and not just memorize a bunch of syntax. Thanks in advance I really need help.

Comment: Pick a small project, try to code it. Look up problems as you come across them, it'll take a while, but you'll start learning and getting better.

Comment: A normal person takes precautions before a problem happens. A programmer solves a problem after it happens. Because otherwise, you will get lost in the endless ocean of possible bugs trying to prevent every single one, even the ones that may never happen.

Comment: You could read this excellent book that is literally the answer to your question: https://www.nostarch.com/thinklikeaprogrammer.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin That's exactly what happens to me every time I start a project. I begin to overengineer it instead of just doing something.

Comment: You should practice C# before you begin with Unity.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, but @Byte56 are you suggesting try to code pure and basic c# programs in somthing like visual studio or trying to code in unity. I know unity has documentaction and all that but a lot of the explanations are not   easy to understand. I'm learning that in unity there are two sides to pretty much every problem. The coding part and actually using the unity tools, objects, settings, and all the other stuff lol. Which makes it kinda hard to focus just on c#. I don't know what to do lol but thanks for everything guys.

Comment: Yes, if you want to learn programming, make programs. Those *could* be games, but it may help to reduce the noise and just focus on making something like a console application, where you don't have to worry about the visual aspect. For example, it could be a text adventure game like Zork. One of the first projects I worked on was an application that reads Exif data from photos and sorts them into directories based on when the photo was taken. Just keep it simple to get used to coding, don't worry about making a game yet.